# How to run my "C#" application under trustedinstaller account?

Tags: c#

How do I run my application under the `trustedinstaller` account?
I tried creating a Visual Studio setup project and made an `msi`. But even that doesn't run under the `trustedinstaller` account. It runs only under the system account.

Can someone please guide me on how I can run my windows application under trusted installer account?

Just in-case you're wonder why I need it, its because I am supposed to copy some files into the `winsxs` folder for the client's `C++` application to work.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you are supposed to do it.  You are meant to mark your .msi as requiring administrator rights and then the system will show the user a UAC elevation dialog when they install.

This [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2007.06.acl.aspx) has more details on Trusted Installer. The bottom line is that it's not actually a user but a service. In any case, it's not the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply david.What is the solution to my problem then?

Comment: You need to mark your .msi as requiring administrator rights. Then when the user installs the system will show the UAC elevation dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately, marking my msi to ask for admin previlages does not work David. Admin previlages doesn't give me access to write into that directory :( I really need some help in impersonating as TrustedInstaller.

Comment: You can't impersonate TrustedInstaller. It's not a user. It's a service.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone please guide me on how I can run my windows application under trusted installer account?

You can use [devxexec](http://blog.developex.com/?p=1053)

For example:

```
devxexec.exe /user:TrustedInstaller cmd
```

Comment: well, 404 on the download page.

Answer (score 2):

Give one of these two utilities a try. **DO NOT TAKE OWNERSHIP as suggested in other answers! This could break things worse than whatever small thing you are trying to do!**

### Method 1: Run as SYSTEM using PsExec

Download PsTools from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

`psexec -s -i <path\to\executable`

The -s option causes it to impersonate SYSTEM. -i makes it interactive.

This seems to handle most cases - even though it is system, it seems to be able to edit TrustedInstaller owned keys.

### Method 2: Theoretically impersonate TrustedInstaller using Nirsoft AdvancedRun

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html

This free tool is from Nirsoft (a long-standing, trustworthy provider of awesome utilities), and can be used in GUI and command line mode.

This explicitly allows you to select a specific service account, although the process shows up running as SYSTEM, it seems to be able to edit TrustedInstaller owned things.

Comment: A great alternative to AdvancedRun, is [PowerRun](https://www.sordum.org/9416/powerrun-v1-6-run-with-highest-privileges/). It also can be used in GUI and command line mode.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `devxexec.exe /user:TrustedInstaller cmd` does not work in Windows 8.
It does run other programs fine though, but not `cmd`.

Comment: It also does not appear to work under Win7. I also tried running explorer and that fails for a permission error.

Comment: It fails likely because the explorer automatically reuses some existing user process or launches a new one under user name. Try launching some explorer substitute, for example like xplorer2 (or any other of many similar softwares, just mentioned the first that popped to my mind). Even launching notepad and doing Your file operations in it's File Open dialog should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done, instead you must:

1. Run with Administrator rights.
2. Take ownership of the object (registry key/directory/whatever).
3. Allow yourself r/w access by changing the DACL.
4. Now make your changes.
5. Set the owner back to trusted installer and undo the permission changes you've made.